# Stringify first level macro expansion C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Is it possible to stringify this C macro:

```
 #define GPIO_INT_PIN (GPIO_PORT_D|GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING|GPIO_PIN5)
```

using something like

```
 MY_STRINGFY(GPIO_INT_PIN)
```

to get

`"(GPIO_PORT_D|GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING|GPIO_PIN5)"` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My purpose is to print a debug message about GPIO_INT_PIN that shows which GPIO is being initialized. GPIO_INT_PIN itself is defined on a .h file, and it can change from version to version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Read about [stringizing](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html) in GCC `cpp` documentation.

```
 #define STRINGIFY(It) #It
 #define MY_STRINGIFY(It) STRINGIFY(It)
```

<sup>I corrected my answer thanks to [Wojtek Surowka's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310084/841108)</sup>

then use `MY_STRINGIFY(GPIO_PORT_D|GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING|GPIO_PIN5)` which would work much better if you use an `enum` to define the constants, e.g.

```
enum Gpio_stuff_en {
     GPIO_PORT_D=5,
     GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING=17,
     GPIO_PIN5=23
};
```

Of course that won't work as you want if you need `GPIO_PORT_D` to be a macro, .e.g. because it expands to some non-constant-literal expression (like a variable, or an access to a field of some global structure, etc....)

As a counter-example:

```
#define FOO 1
#define BAR 2
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define MY_STRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY(s)

MY_STRINGIFY(FOO|BAR)
```

is expanded to `"1|2"`  not to `"FOO|BAR"`, if your remove the two `#define`-s for `FOO` and for `BAR` and replace them with

```
enum {
  FOO=1,
  BAR=2 };
```

you really get the expansion `"FOO|BAR"` as you want. Check with `gcc -C -E` ...

Also:

```
enum {FOO=1, BAR=2};
#define FOOORBAR (FOO|BAR)
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define MY_STRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY(s)

MY_STRINGIFY(FOOORBAR)
```

is expanded as `"(FOO|BAR)"` . But if you use `#define` for `FOO` and for `BAR` you get the `"(1|2)"` expansion.

Maybe you could add in your own header, after including the external header defining `GPIO_PORT_D` etc... as a literal constants, something like :

```
enum {en_GPIO_PORT_D= GPIO_PORT_D,
      en_GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING= GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING,
      en_GPIO_PIN5= GPIO_PIN5};
#undef GPIO_PORT_D
#undef GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING 
#undef GPIO_PIN5
#define GPIO_PORT_D en_GPIO_PORT_D
#define GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING en_GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING
#define GPIO_PIN5 en_GPIO_PIN5
```

and then you'll get more readable stringified constants (but not exactly what you dream of).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer, but i don't think i can change the defines to enums because i'm not the maintainer of the file that defines them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have such two definitions

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define MY_STRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY(s)
```

MY_STRINGIFY does what you want - expands its argument and adds quotes after.

Comment: But I think the OP might not want `GPIO_PORT_D` to be expanded.

Comment: It is said clearly: I want MY_STRINGFY(GPIO_INT_PIN) to expand to "(GPIO_PORT_D|GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING|GPIO_PIN5)" - sorry misread your concern (skipped the _D :))

Comment: I don't think it is possible then - either you get GPIO_INT_PIN not expanded, or fully expanded

Comment: The problem is that GPIO_PORT_D, GPIO_PIN_IRQ_RISING and GPIO_PIN5 are  macros too. I don't want them to be expanded, i only want to expand GPIO_INT_PIN.